# Where on memory are struct fields allocated if we allocate struct with malloc?

Tags: c, malloc, overflow, heap-memory

Here we have a struct, then, we allocate an instance of it with malloc:

```
typedef struct _MyStruct {
    struct *nextStruct;
    char array[4];
} MyStruct

/* Allocates space on heap for the struct */
_MyStruct *m = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
printf("%zu bytes\n", sizeof(MyStruct)); /* Outputs: 8 bytes */

int r;

/* We intentionally overflow the buffer inside of the struct */
r = (int)gets(m->array); /* Input */
    if (r == 0)
         return;
```

As per what I have understood so far. Are these affirmations correct?

1. When we populate the string 'abcde' (5 bytes), we overrun the char array inside the struct, which resides on the stack.
2. If we insert the string 'abcdefghi' (9 bytes), we overrun the struct itself, which I assume is on the heap. But we also overrun the char array on the stack.

**Edit**: To be more accurate, this question is based on the C99 standard, implemented by an i686 O.S.

Comment: No, the struct m including the char array is completely on the heap, not on the stack. If you have a heap... or a stack... or whatever ;)

Comment: I understand it clearly :). I am reading multiple guides and I ended messing it up. Cheers mate.

Comment: There is no stack in the C language.

Comment: What is wrong with the question? 3 downvotes , I would appreciate critics on it.

Comment: @Roizpi: Please provide a reference to the standard about a stack and a heap. You confuse a **specific** implementation and the language. None is required for a compliant implementation. And most implementations for x86, ARM, MIPS, etc. don't always use the stack.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I may have obviated the architecture of my machine, but I implicitly asked for one which has stack. As I found a conflict on the theory I have leant. I was taught that variables are on stack, whereas struct instantiated with malloc goes on the heap. Nice review though.

Comment: @Olaf I have edited my question with the reference. Please, reconsider the vote, I dont ask for an upvote, but to rectify a negative one :). Thanks.

Comment: A stack overflow link is not a reference to the standard. How about getting a better book or doing proper research before making wrong assumptions? If you got them from a teacher/prof: you should ask for **authoritative** references. And learn about undefined behaviour. There is no use in asking how/why the code you show behaves. It is just not possible to answer comprehensively.

Comment: You are right, SO may not be the best reference. The book I am reading along with the teachers of my course, trust me, they are good. It is me, that strangely didn't born with all the knowledge in the world, and have to ask questions to understand what I read. I would better edit the question clarifying that my question was "broadly speaking". :)

Comment: @Olaf is right about this: *And learn about undefined behaviour. There is no use in asking how/why the code you show behaves. It is just not possible to answer comprehensively*. Which is probably why you are getting downvotes.

Comment: I will keep this advice in mind for further questions.

Comment: @MFisherKDX: I normally don't reply to insulting posts. However, it is most important for beginner to understand and get the abstraction layers right. OP started with a wrong assumption already. A stack trace is something very different and part of the implementation. There is also a difference betweeen the call-stack (what the stack-trace is about) and where local variables are allocated for implementations wich do use a stack for that (and e.g. modern x86/64 implementations/ABIs does not use the stack for all local variables typically). Remember posters are expected to understand the problem

Comment: The standard mentions *neither* the word *stack*, *nor* the word *heap*. The actual implementations can also work *as if*. Also, the cast to `int` of the `gets` return value is somewhat strange as the conversion is an implementation detail, and `r == 0` would work just fine if `r` was a pointer. Also the compiler is allowed to do range checking so it is allowed to change your `gets` to `fgets` that will protect you from overflowing the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When we populate the string 'abcde' (5 bytes), we overrun the char array inside the struct, which resides on the stack.

No, the struct, and its associated elements are created dynamically via `malloc`.  So the entire struct, including the char array lies on the heap.

Comment: I really can continue with my work swiftly with this answer. The thing is I can't expend many time debugging and analysing memory addresses right now. But I can figure out everything now. Thank you!

Comment: So when overriding the char array, it is the char array individually which is overriding on the heap?

Comment: No. If you overwrite the bounds of your char array, you'll cause undefined behavior -- probably corrupting whatever memory lies beyond it. Since C does not allow the compiler to reorder the elements of a struct you should not *expect* the same struct's `nextstruct` pointer value to be corrupted -- because it would be located at a lower memory address. However because this is UB, anything *could* happen.

Answer (score -1):

You are overwriting the adress of the struct on the heap, not the struct on the heap itself, assuming you meant the pointer to next struct